# Problem with glob operator with for loop

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I am trying to traverse all files in /home directory recursively. I want to do some linux command with each file . So, I am making use of for loop as below:

```
for i in /home/**/*
```

I have put below statements as start of script as well:

- shopt -s globstar
- shopt -s nullglob

But its getting stuck in for loop. It might be the problem with handling so many files.
If I give some another directory(with less no of files) to for loop loop, then it traverse properly.

What else I can try.

Complete Code:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s globstar
shopt -s nullglob
echo "ggg"
for i in /home/**/*
do
    NAME=${i}
    echo "It's there." $NAME
    if [ -f "$i" ]; then
        echo "It's there." $NAME
        printf "\n\n"
    fi
done
```

Comment: I don't understand. You say that when you don't have many files it works but when you have many files it takes a long time. That's entirely normal. What is the problem here? This is an incredibly slow way to count files. What are you trying to do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/66635949/1030675

Comment: @terdon, I did not say that it is taking time. Its just stuck in for loop statement. It is not going inside at all.

Comment: Yes, it is trying to find all the files. As Kusalananda explains below, the `**/*` will need to be expanded to the list of all matching files and directories before the loop can begin. If you wait long enough, the loop will start.

Answer (score 6):

The shell needs to expand the pattern `/home/**/*` *fully* before starting the first iteration of your loop.  If you have many files, it would naturally take some time before it could actually start looping.  If you observed your shell process in e.g. `top`, you would notice that its memory consumption would gradually increase as it builds the list of all files and directories under `/home`.

To count the number of regular files in a directory structure, it would be better to use `find`.

```
find /home -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

This would print a line of output for each regular file in or under `/home`, and `wc` would count these lines, giving you the sum at the end.

To avoid hidden files:

```
find /home ! -name '.*' -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

To additionally avoid hidden directories (which your shell loop also does):

```
find /home -name '.*' -prune -o -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

The reason I'm counting empty lines with `wc -l` instead of counting pathnames outputted by `-print`, is that pathnames may possibly contain newlines, in which case `wc -l` would get the count wrong.

---

Regarding symbolic links: Your shell loop follows symbolic links, so if you have symbolically linked directories, your loop would enter these, and if you have symbolic links to regular files, your loop would count these.

The `find` solutions above would *not* follow symbolic links.  You would use the `-L` option to `find` to get a similar behavior.

```
find -L /home -type f -printf '\n' | wc -l
```

---

Users of non-GNU `find` could use `-exec echo \;` in place of `-printf '\n'`.